# Dedicated Web application and separate URL domain

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, health-analyzer, mysite

**

> Validate the My Site Host and individual My Sites are on a dedicated
>   Web application and separate URL domain.

**

How to resolve ??

Comment: What are you asking, are you asking why you are getting this message and how to make it go away?

Comment: Yes how to resolve and why this?

Comment: Waqas has given you the short answe below, you have not set up your my site host on a dedicated web application

Answer (score 2):

Cause:   The My Site host and individual My Sites are deployed in the same Web application as the root site collection. If the User Profile Service was configured by using the Farm Configuration Wizard, this is how My Sites are set up.

how to resolve the SharePoint Health Analyzer rule "Validate the My Site Host and individual My Sites are on a dedicated Web application and separate URL domain."

Fix: Set up a dedicated Web application, We recommend that you have a separate, dedicated Web application to host the My Site host and individual My Sites. Unless you are using Host-Named Site Collection deployment.

here is step by step instruction to setup MySite...
http://myspexp.com/2010/06/14/setting-up-mysite-as-a-different-application-2/

Comment: In the past, where Path-Based Site Collections (PBSC) deployment was common, Microsoft recommended to host your My Site in a separate web application. Host-Named Site Collection (HNSC) deployment is now the recommended deployment by Microsoft, based on their deployment of Office 365. In HNSC deployment, it best to configure two web applications, a web application to host the Central Administration website, another to host everything else. You still have to plan your content DB break-down based on your business requirements.

Comment: Thank you for down vote, but did you read the question....my answer was the response of the question ( the error user getting). But what u saying is another way to do the things but still both methods are valid....but ur comment did not fix the problem op had.

Comment: You're right I removed my down vote